# How to link and compile .c and .so file in linux

Tags: c

I am having crt284utest.c and crt_284u.so file. In crt284utest.c file i used dlopen(), dlclose(), dlsym(). Now i am trying to compile using following commands:
 gcc c -O crt284utest.c
While compiling the above command the error is as follows:
gcc.real: c: No such file or directory
and then
gcc crt_284u.o -ldl -o crt284utest
While compiling the above command the error is as follows:
gcc.real: crt_284u.o: No such file or directory

Comment: It's not `c`, it's `-c`. Right now you try to compile a *source file* named `c`, when you mean to pass the option `-c` to tell the compiler to create an object file. It should be pretty clear by just reading the error message.

Comment: Because the object file is named `crt284utest.o` and not `crt_284u.o`.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go how to compile in linux using gcc ::

**$ gcc -o firstprogram firstprogram.c**

If your file is named firstprogram.c then type '-o firstprogram' as the parameter to gcc. This is basically your suggested name for the executable file that gcc would create. In case you typed something like the following

**$ gcc firstprogram.c**

You would be having a a.out in the same directory as the source C file. This is the default name of the executable that gcc creates. This would create problems when you compile many programs in one directory. So you override this with the -o option followed by the name of the executable

**$ gcc -o hello secondprogram.c**

Would create an executable by the name hello for your source code named secondprogram.c

Running the executable that you created is as simple as typing the following at the prompt.

**$ ./firstprogram**
OR
**$ ./hello**